# Nginx to introspect OAUTH token

Tags: nginx, keycloak

I am setting an Nginx reverse proxy that routes requests to various backend microservices based on path. Additionally, before routing requests, I would like Nginx to verify the validity of the oauth token passed in request header. I use Keycloak as oauth server, though I could introspect the token from other applications (and postman) I find it hard to implement in Nginx.

`nginx.conf`

```
map $http_authorization $token {
  ~*^Bearer\s+([\S]+)$ $1;
}

location / {
  auth_request /auth;
  error_page 401 =401 /auth;
  proxy_pass http://backend-api/; 
}
```

---

Token verify block

```
location = /auth {
  # internal;
  gunzip on;
  proxy_method POST;
  proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic base64encoded-uid-pwd";
  proxy_set_header Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  proxy_set_body "token=$token";
  proxy_pass https://keycloak-server/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect;

  # proxy_cache           token_responses; # Enable caching of token introspection responses
  # proxy_cache_key       $access_token;   # Cache the response for each unique access token
  # proxy_cache_lock      on;              # Don't allow simultaneous requests for same token
  # proxy_cache_valid     200 10s;         # How long to use cached introspection responses
  # proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout;   # Use old responses if we cannot reach the server
  # proxy_ignore_headers  Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie; # Cache even when receiving these

}
```

The Nginx is send the request to the Keycloak server, I have verified the log, but I get the below error response from Keycloak

```
{
"active": false
}
```

I found this error was due to the token not properly passed as body param in the request. What am I missing in the script? Actually I have to take only the auth token passed in `Authorization` header and pass it to the Keycloak server in body param.

PS: The Keycloak expects the oauth token as param in the `x-www-form-urlencoded` body as `token`.

Comment: you may want to look at https://github.com/zmartzone/ngx_oauth2_module which offers a lot more flexibility in terms of token endpoint authentication and caching

Comment: @vvra did you get this to run? If so what config did you use?

Comment: I tried this now with the kubernetes ingress-nginx but without success... not sure what goes wrong.
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/9910

Comment: I believe `proxy_set_body "token=$token"` should be `proxy_set_body "token=$http_token"`.